# C auto variable isn't freed after function return

Tags: c

I have the following C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct num {
  int a;
  struct num *c;
} num;

void init_struct(num *n) {
  num some_num = { 1 };

  n->c = &some_num;
}

int main() {
  num *n = malloc(sizeof(num));
  init_struct(n);

  printf("%d\n", (n->c)->a);
  return 0;
}
```

From my understanding, the call to `printf("%d\n", (n->c)->a)` should result in a segmentation fault, since it's accessing a memory that is freed already. But in fact, it returns 1.

My reasoning is as follows:

- When `init_struct` is called, it creates a `some_num` struct with its `a` member set to 1, its address is assigned to `n->c`, then it is freed.
- `n->c` now keeps the address of a freed struct, calling `(n->c)->a` should result in a segmentation fault.

Turns out it's not the case, but I don't know why.

I'm running this with `gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)`

Comment: It is undefined behavior. A segmentation fault is one of many possible results.

Comment: If someone created a unique C compiler implementation each day for the rest of your life, you could spend the rest of your life answering those "why" questions. It would be better for you to answer questions that are based upon defined behavior, not undefined behavior.

Comment: Exact duplicate at another site: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Comment: @tiendo1011: Instead of adding a paragraph *this question has been answered* in the question, you should accept one of the answers by clicking on the gray checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, it's freed all right. To quote Raymond Chen, "appearing to work is undefined behavior, but it's still undefined."

Accessing a pointer to what was a stack variable will not segfault, and is disgustingly likely to work in a toy example. Nothing actually checks that you access free stack. That would be too slow. So it just doesn't, and you get whatever was there last.

The value to be printed is being computed directly in `main()` and in x64, the slot to which it will be pushed for the `printf` call is already allocated at the top of `main()`; thus nothing has the chance to overwrite the value. However, if the process were to receive a signal in between, the value will be stomped in the signal handler and there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: *if the process were to receive a signal in between...* of course this is not guaranteed either. Signals are handled with a separate stack on recent desktop systems, so receiving a signal no longer affects the current thread's stack.

Comment: @chqrlie: That has to be initialized in userspace (see man 2 signalstack) and on running `strace /bin/true` I found it was not initialized by default. Most likely, it is not turned on until the thread library is used to avoid confusing single-threaded programs.

Answer (score 2):

Just to demonstrate that this is Undefined Behavior I ran your code as is, and got your result = 1

then I ran this code

```
int main() {
    num* n = malloc(sizeof(num));
    init_struct(n);
    fopen("not here", "r"); <<<<====
    printf("%d\n", (n->c)->a);
    return 0;
}
```

and got

```
 -242574432
```

You got the worst kind of UB, it appeared to work fine, but it will fail in the middle of the busiest day of your most demanding customer